# Ajax and MVC 4 ( post request)

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to send a simple string ( which is xml ) to a controller. I don't know why the breakpoint in Visual Studio is not hit.

Here is the jQuery code :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "BasicWizard/show",
            data: "xml="+xmlResult,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Oh yeah !");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }


            });
```

And here is my method in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult show(string xml)

   {
       try
       {
           ViewBag.xml = xml;
           return PartialView("showXML");
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           return Content("error");
       }


    }
```

I have just a 500 error in the console.

Comment: any errors in firebug/console?

Comment: What's your controller method look like?

Comment: I have this : POST http://localhost:2424/BasicWizard/show 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:130
error undefined

Comment: Provide us with the details (body) of this 500 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :-

```
data: "{'xml':'" + xmlResult+ "'}",
```

Comment: It's working thanks a lot ! I am used to work with MVC 3, and the way I was writting was working but now I will do like this !

Comment: Don't forget to hit that nice little check mark next to the post then so others can find :D

Comment: If you want to use JSON, you need a little more than just this - you still need to properly encode it, and tell the AJAX call your content type. so your data would need to be `JSON.stringify({xml:xmlResult})`, and your call would need to include the `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"` parameter.

Comment: I have a other problem, it is normal that in the controller xml is null ( I do an alert of xmlResult before sending it, it's not null ! ) ?

Comment: add contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", in ajax request

Comment: If I had this line, xml is not null in the controller but it's not the string I want, there is a lot of strange chars !

Comment: SO now, i have something like this in result : " &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; ?" Do you know how I can get rid of this ?

Answer (score 0):

The post data isn't properly formatted. Try passing in `encodeURIComponent(xmlResult)` instead of just `xmlResult`. This will escape out the `=` and other characters that won't work properly in a post value.